# Prove that the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) $ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

I have the problem with this divergent series:

$$\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) $$

Since $\ \sin x \leq x $:

$$\ \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) <  \frac{1}{\sqrt n} /*\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$
$$\ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) <  \frac{1}{ n}$$

However, to prove divergence, the inequality should point the different direction. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

For $0 \leq x \leq \frac\pi2$, we have
$$\frac{2}{\pi} x \leq \sin(x) \leq x \,.$$
One of these inequalities is the one you want.

Comment: Therefore I use $\ \frac{2}{\pi}x \leq \sin(x), x = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} $, and get after multiplication $\ \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{ n} \leq \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) $. Is it enough to prove?

Comment: Exactly, and you can conclude by the comparison test that the series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

A variant is to use $\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$ and in particular this term is $>\frac 12$ for $|u|\ll 1$ small enough.

Now write $\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\dfrac 1n\times\dfrac{\sin(\frac 1{\sqrt{n}})}{\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}}>\dfrac 1n\times\dfrac 12$ for $n$ large enough.

And still conclude by comparison with $\sum\frac 1n$.

*Note: a faster way is to use equivalents, the limit $1$ means $\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sin(\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n}}){}\sim \dfrac 1n$.*